# TinyMCE Filemanager and Imagemanager

Tags: php, javascript, image, file, tinymce

We have both the Tinymce Filemanager and Imagemanager.

I need to intergrate the two of them together.
On the webpage of the Imagemaneger it says it is compatible with the Filemanager.

( http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php ).

However I can not find anywhere how this works. I don't want the Imagemanager and Filemanager to be seperated. It would be ideal to have both of them seemlesly working together.

Does anyone know where to find a demo and how to intergrate this?

Thanks in advance,

-V

Comment: +1 you might give the tinymce forum a try

Comment: Ill try, their website is a little slow tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, after a while.

I don't remember where I found the solution but it was one hell of a search.

In the filemanager `config.php` file you have to edit the lines `152/153/154/155`
The `$mcFileManagerConfig["imagemanager.urlprefix"]` is most important, you have to set the url to where the imagemanager plugin is located.

The same goes for the imagemanager  `config.php` on line 128 edit the `$mcImageManagerConfig['filemanager.urlprefix']` to the imagemanager path.